# xml auto messing up my rich text data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a rich text editor that saves my markup to the database. I have a stored procedure that uses XML Auto to bring back that data. The problem, you probably already guessed, XML Auto encodes my markup so the rich text doesn't display on my web page display. Only the markup literals show.

Is there something in XML Auto I can do to prevent certain fields from getting encoded? Other ideas welcomed.

**XML**

```
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <album>Thriller</album>
    <artist>Michael Jackson</artist>
    <notes>&lt;strong&gt;test&lt;/strong&gt;</notes>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <album>Album2</album>
    <artist>Artist2</artist>
    <notes>Can be plain text as well.</notes>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

**c# XSLT**

```
        string xmlFile = @"XMLFile.xml"; //<view>html column</view>
        string xslFile = @"XSLTFile.xslt"; //views.xsl file
        string xmlFilePath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + xmlFile;
        string xsltPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + xslFile;

        XPathDocument xPathDoc = new XPathDocument(xmlFilePath);
        XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
        transform.Load(xsltPath);
        transform.Transform(xPathDoc, null, Response.Output);
```

Comment: are you referring to special characters like the ampersand/spaces?

Comment: have you considered decoding the incoming XML data on the client during pageload/postback?

Comment: Is there a way to add something to the xsl that will decode the xml?

Comment: sorry, I'm no XSL pro...I assumed you were passing everything to a browser.  you can certainly accomplish the decoding in javascript, but I'm not sure if that's an option for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An "XML" with *unenconded* [reserved chars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145315%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) is illegal. So it's not possible to have an XML like this `<root>a&b</root>` because `&` char is reserved. Solution is to decode strings before use:

```
DECLARE @x XML;
SET @x = (SELECT 'a&b' AS Col FOR XML RAW)

SELECT @x AS StringEncoded
SELECT @x.value('(/row/@Col)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS StringDecoded
```

Results:

```
StringEncoded
---------------------
<row Col="a&amp;b" />

StringDecoded
---------------------
a&b
```

Second example:

```
DECLARE @x2 XML;
SET @x2 = (SELECT '<strong>test</strong>' AS Col FOR XML RAW)

SELECT @x2 AS StringEncoded2
SELECT @x2.value('(/row/@Col)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS StringDecoded2
```

Results:

```
StringEncoded2
-----------------------------------------------
<row Col="&lt;strong&gt;test&lt;/strong&gt;" />

(1 row(s) affected)

StringDecoded2
-----------------------------------------------
<strong>test</strong>
```

Comment: what if the resulting xml is part of an xsl transform, is there hope to do something with decoding

Comment: @Rod: Add an example for clarification.

Comment: I updated the OP. Please take a look. Thanks for any and all feedback.

Comment: @Rod: XSL transformation has nothing to do with "your problem". You should  decode the strings before use. Of course, instead of deconding using T-SQL (see my **second example**), you could try to decode using [HtmlDecode method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2).